# Firebase using Node Js function notification not receiving in android but it work directly from firebase panel

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, android-notifications

i am trying to implement notification in android app. i implement the code and receiving notification into my android device from Firebase panel directly. and when i trying to use node js method its not working . i am using third party web services in android device please

below code is my node js function code.
please help me i already check and search on many site but this type of problem not founded , thanks in advance

this same code i already implement in my old application and work fine but those application fully connected with firebase . but this current app i am using web services.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("./xxxxxxx-xxxxx-firebase-adminsdk-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://xxxxxxx-xxxxx.firebaseio.com"
});

//Notification Method
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("/Notifications/{first_id}")
.onCreate((snapshot,context)=>{

     const id=context.params.first_id;
     const data2=snapshot.val()
     var token=data2.Token
     var text= data2.Name

// Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
// registration token.


     return Promise.all([token,text]).then(results =>{

            var payload = {
                     data:{
                          username: "name",
                          usertoken: token,
                          notificationTitle: "name1",
                          notificationMessage: "ntest"
                       }
                   };

             return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
      })

})
```

```java
<!-- Notification Services Manifest file-->
        <service
            android:name=".FCM_Serivces.MyFirebaseNotificationService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/> <!-- Get Notification -->
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".FCM_Serivces.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>  <!-- Get Token Id -->
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

```java
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        registerToken(token);
    }

    private void registerToken(String token) {

    }
}
```

```java
//Java Class
public class MyFirebaseNotificationService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {

            SendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        }
    }


    private void SendNotification(String title,String msg){
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(msg);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(false);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSound);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

```java
//Gradle 

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:16.1.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.8'
```

```java
//i use this code in click lister for send data with token for notification
DatabaseReference referenceNotification =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notifications").push();
                Map<String,String> mMap=new HashMap<>();

                mMap.put("Name","01");
                mMap.put("Token", FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
                mMap.put("Title","Test");
                mMap.put("Message","1234");
                referenceNotification.setValue(mMap)
```

i receive on log this result of function 
"Function execution took 501 ms, finished with status: 'ok'"

Comment: Can you provide you App class That receives the notification? It should inherit from FirebaseMessagingService

Comment: @RanderGabriel i updated the code please check and help me , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The method getToken() is deprecated. You can use getInstanceId()
>   instead.

For getting device token and saving it for further use:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(this, instanceIdResult -> {
    String newToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();
    Log.e("newToken", newToken);
    getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("myToken", newToken).apply();
});
```

On saving to database:

```
mMap.put("Token", 
getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("myToken", "empty :("));
```

Now use the token send a notification using node server:

```
//Notification Method
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("/Notifications/{first_id}")
.onCreate((snapshot,context)=>{

     const id=context.params.first_id;
     const data2=snapshot.val()
     var token=data2.Token
     var text= data2.Name

         var payload = {
                 data:{
                      username: "name",
                      usertoken: token,
                      notificationTitle: "name1",
                      notificationMessage: "ntest"
                   },
                   token: deviceRegistrationToken
               };

    admin.messaging().send(payload)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("success");
            return null;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

}
```

Comment: i try this code and the result is success , but problem is still same . may be java code issue i updated my code in question and add java code , please check and help me , and thanks for this answer

Comment: Are you registering the device token?

Comment: i add two more codes in my code , that how i write MyFirebaseInstanceIDService class for get token and second how i send data to firebase with token

Comment: I've updated my answer. getToken() is deprecated. Use getInstanceId() as I've shown in my code.